# In opennms datacollection-config.xml file is showing error, what may be wrong?

Tags: opennms

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<datacollection-config rrdRepository="/var/lib/opennms/rrd/snmp/">
  <snmp-collection name="default12" snmpStorageFlag="select">
    <rrd step="300">
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:2016</rra>
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:1488</rra>
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:366</rra>
      <rra>RRA:MAX:0.5:288:366</rra>
      <rra>RRA:MIN:0.5:288:366</rra>
    </rrd>


<resourceType name="testResourceType" label="CISCOTESTRESOURCETYPE" >
  <persistenceSelectorStrategy class="org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.PersistAllSelectorStrategy"/>
  <storageStrategy class="org.opennms.netmgt.dao.support.FrameRelayStorageStrategy"/>
</resourceType>



    <group name="ciscotestgroup" ifType="all">
 <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5"          instance="testResourceType" alias="sysName"         type="string" />
 <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2"      instance="testResourceType" alias="ifDescr"         type="string" />
 <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18"  instance="testResourceType" alias="ifAlias"         type="counter" />
      </group>

  <systemDef name="ciscorouterstest">
    <sysoidMask>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.<sysoidMask>
    <collect>
      <includeGroup>ciscotestgroup</includeGroup>
    </collect>
  </systemDef>


  </snmp-collection>
</datacollection-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block of code:

```
<systemDef name="ciscorouterstest">
  <sysoidMask>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.<sysoidMask>
  <collect>
    <includeGroup>ciscotestgroup</includeGroup>
  </collect>
</systemDef>
```

You need to close the `<sysoidMask>` element:

```
  <sysoidMask>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.</sysoidMask>
```

If you're going to be mucking about with XML configuration files, you should learn how to use an XML validator, which would have spotted this for you automatically.  There are a variety of tools for this, such as `tidy` and `xmllint`.  Most editors can auto-indent your XML code, and this will also help spot errors.

Comment: Hey... Thanks for your help. But still the opennms not starting with modified datacollection-config.xml file.

Comment: Hmmm, you're beyond me, then; I'm not familiar with OpenNMS.  Typical suggestions at this point would be to look for errors in the logs and/or start up the software with verbose debugging enabled.